# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Invalid index 0, size is 0

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics

I use Firebase Crashlytics and I see a lot of my users have this crash issue.
I can't find any solutions to this problem and 40% of my users are crashing because of this error. How can I solve this?

Thank you.

```
"Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Invalid index 0, size is 0"

ui.TracksAdapter.getItem (TracksAdapter.java:54)

ui.TracksAdapter.getItemId (TracksAdapter.java:59)
```

My TracksAdapter Code:

```
public TracksAdapter(Context context, List<Track> rowItems) {
    this.context = context;
    this.trackItems = rowItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return trackItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    pos = position;
    return trackItems.get(position); // Line 54.
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return trackItems.indexOf(getItem(position)); // Line 59
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always check the argument that you are passing to your adapter's constructor not to be null and not to be empty, but if you don't, you can check this inside `getItem` method:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    pos = position;
    if (trackItems != null && trackItems.size() > position) {
        return trackItems.get(position); // Line 54.
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check if `getCount() > position` that is to confirm **trackItems** has items in it before calling `getItemId` and `getItem`